# how to bind data in wpf application for icard print system and print

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want to make a i-card printing system I am new to w.p.f. I want to **print 10 i-card at one time** so I have to  bind it once and that with in proper print format please advise what to do.

**please help me .**

I tried many things.

```
<ListView Margin="10"   Height="300" Name="lvDataBinding" VerticalAlignment="Top" UseLayoutRounding="True" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate  >
            <DataTemplate   >
                <WrapPanel Background="Red" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"  Margin="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >


                    <i card disply here  />



                </WrapPanel>

            </DataTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>



List<User> items = new List<User>();
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42 });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39 });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 13 });
        lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = items;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example of binding in a ListView:

```
<ListView Margin="10"   Height="300" Name="lvDataBinding" VerticalAlignment="Top" UseLayoutRounding="True" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Obviously, you need to format it better - like adding a Margin to one of the `TextBoxes` etc. You can also use a `Grid` and the [SharedSizeGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: please suggest how to use it in printing 10 icard at one time i want to have functionality like repeater where template increase as row of selected data increases. that too in format of i card like photo on left then in right name and other info then next i card in proper format .

Comment: thank you for your reply @Troels Larsen 
but data shown in it I cannot able to format , can I put another parent control in list view and then place textblock in it? please help.

Comment: @NarenderKumar: I'm not sure what you mean. You can replace the StackPanel with a Grid or any other panel. Basically, the ListView will create a series of controls based on the ItemTemplate specified, which will have the DataContext set to each individual item. If you use my example, don't you see anything?